# Why does ffmpeg accept .txt files as input?

Tags: ffmpeg

I just learned ffmpeg accepts .txt files and renders the content.
See:

```
ffmpeg -i bees.txt -r 2 bees.gif
```

[image: Result]

Where can i find more information about this behavior (docs/sourcecode ?), and are there other "magic" file endings like this ?
It looks like ffmpeg ignores the file ending in almost all other cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "possible duplicate answer" helped me find my answer.

It is the **tty Demuxer**

> Demuxer tty [Tele-typewriter]:
>       Common extensions: ans,art,asc,diz,ice,nfo,txt,vt.